# on the convergence of an infinite series involving logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, logarithms

It looks like the following quantity
$$
q(k)=\frac{k+1}{2k}(1+\log k) - \sum_{i=2}^k \frac{i}{k^2} \log i
$$
tends to $3/4$ as $k$ goes to infinity.

Is there a nice way to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i}{k^2} \log i=\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i}{k}\log(i)=\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i}{k}(\log(\frac ik)+\log(k))=\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i}{k}\log(\frac ik)+\log(k)\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i}{k}
$$
Now use Riemann integration definition.

Comment: Thanks! So actually $$q(k)=\frac{k+1}{2k}-\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i}{k}\log(\frac ik)$$ which tends to $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$, remembering that $\int x\log x=\frac{1}{4}x^2(2 \log x-1)+const$

Comment: You're welcome, If you're new to the site, you can accept an answer or give an upvote to a usefull answer...for more information you can take a tour in the site...